# Converting payload of NFC tag to URL adds extra characters to URL and makes it invalid address

Tags: ios, swift, url, nfc, core-nfc

I am trying this code and my desired URL is [www.tapaway.com.au](https://tapaway.com.au) but what I am getting is https://%02tapaway.com.au. I have write the first URL [www.tapaway.com.au](https://tapaway.com.au) on my NFC tag so whenever someone scans the tag it opens my webpage. My code is

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    var result = ""
      for payload in messages[0].records{
          print("-> \(payload)") //Prints the Entire NFC Payload on the Tag.
        result += String.init(data: payload.payload, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         var components = URLComponents()
         components.scheme = "https"
         components.host = "\(result)"
         components.path = "/"
         let url = components.url
         print(url)
         UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So a URL is stored in an encoded form in NDEF records to save space.

The `%02` is the code for the URI Identifier, "https://www." in this case
The `tapaway.com.au` is the URI payload

So when correctly decode the URL is "https://www.tapaway.com.au" to which you would be adding "https" on the front again.

So you need to decode the payload correctly before you can use it as a URL.
The 1st byte is the URI Identifier.
All other bytes are the shortened URL

See the Specification document for this type of NDEF record at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf

It seems there is a convenience function for this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcndefpayload/3153117-wellknowntypeuripayload

so probably (I'm not a swift programmer)

```
var url = payload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload()
```

Comment: How could I convert it to URL can you please help me with this

Comment: Updated as it seems iOS seems to have a convenience function for this